# Very strange app.exe hangs on start

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, startup, freeze

I develop .NET application for a 6 years but today I faced with really strange behavior.

After I copy my application files (.exe, .dll, configs etc.) onto another machine I found that double click on .exe file deadly hangs the app. Waiting cursor never disappear.

After some time I installed VS 2012 express on that machine and started my project. It starts and runs perfectly. After this I tried to run its' .exe file from ../bin/debug folder. It hangs like the first time.

After this I created empty WPF application. The story repeated itself completely: it perfectly starts from VS but deadly hangs when start from direct exe double click.

So, any (WPF) application starts correctly under VShost but hangs when started from exe file.
May be someone have some ideas about what may going on on this computer?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running (both computers)?

Comment: Why are you deploying the debug version?

Comment: Are you running from a share drive or a local folder on your machine?

Comment: I have deployed WPF .EXE files (RELEASE version) as standalone and work perfectly for me

Comment: I tried also release version. All the same

Comment: this smells of some configuration (VS) or machine setup issue, do you have any setup 'out of ordinary', low on space something. Are you running through RD (doesn't seem relevant just asking). And did you try some other apps, exe etc., anything .NET. Also I assume you restarted the machine.

Comment: Machine restarting is the only way to get rid of hanged instances in my case. Task Manager for some reason can not kill it. Other apps seem to run fine. Fails only created with VS (sounds crazy but it is what I have)

Comment: This type of error ('breakpoint' message you mentioned) is often related to some sort of memory corruption (though could be many things) - and e.g. with C++ - but since you have an empty .NET not sure (maybe again look elsewhere, reinstall some things, VS at least - also look at what is installed at your machine that could interfere). Btw how do you run the VS and explorer (you're clicking from) - as a normal user each time, admin, how is that you're logged in? Though again that's a long-shot.

Comment: @SergeP.when you have more people in comments you need to tag them specifically so they get the notification (start with @...)

Comment: Try downgrading the dotnet version you use. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066930/wpf-window-crashes-on-startup-or-it-starts-but-hangs-and-does-not-render-conten

Answer (score 0):

Some things you could check:

- Do you have any System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached checks in your code?
- Could the current directory cause any differences in behaviour; remember that if you launch VS then you're program will run from there.
- Do you have any tracing in your code; if so, does that give you any information about what the program is trying to do before it hangs?

Comment: I have no Tracing/Debugging or anything else in my code. Actually I have nothing - just create blank WPF application and try to start it from VS (OK) and by double clicking (Hang).

Comment: What configuration are you running?  Also, is this on any PC, or just one?

Comment: The hanging process does not display in regular Task Manager but it does in VS 'Attach To' processes list. When I attach VS debugger to it, VS emits the message '..application has triggered a breakpoint...'. Then VS deadly hangs too

Comment: I tried different configurations: x64, x32, AnyCPU. The problem computer has 32-bit OS

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour with a winforms app?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following (requires Visual Studio onto the target machine and debug version assemblies, so it is kind of convoluted):

- copy relevant sources onto target machine
- start the application from exe in Debug (pdbs should also be there)
- in Visual Studio, open the solution
- attach to process (Ctrl-Alt-P) -> select your executable
- pause the execution

[Specifing Source Files in the Visual Studio Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx) might be required.

Of course, using a detailed logging via a logging library such as [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), could also be helpful.

Comment: problem is he has no code virtually, empty app - he'll end up within some system call or nothing

Comment: When I attach VS debugger to hanged app VS emits the message '..application has triggered a breakpoint...'. When I pause the eqecution VS deadly hangs too